# Secure File Transmission

Tags: android, security, file, ftp

I want actually to develop an Android Prototype which creates a connection to Server and a **secure file exchange** happens between the device and Server.

I'm using a Virtual Webspace with an FTP account.
I have looked up for FTP connections using Android, but these weren't really secure.

Does anyone has any ideas to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could copy over ssh -
there is scp (secure copy) - I know there are jars that allow you to perform ssh / scp.

Gook luck.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using https, you can then POST the file to the web server as multipart form-data.

On Android, use the HttpURLConnection class.